# Getting undefined for firestore document after .get()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I really don't know why I'm getting this annoying undefined after using .get() method,
(This reafctoring this function as contribution for an open source but there 2 line of code was there for more than a moth and worked fine, I don't know why its not working for me)
This is my function:

```
export async function saveUserInFirestore(userData) {
  const userRef = await firestore.collection('users').doc(userData.uid); // Not getting undefined here
  const userDoc = await userRef.get(); // Getting undefined here

  if (userDoc.exists) // The functions crashes {
    return { ...userDoc, exists: true };
  } else {
    const { uid, first_name: initialFirst, last_name: initialLast, displayName, pictureUrl } = userData;
    const updatedUserObject = {
      uid,
      initialFirst,
      initialLast,
      displayName,
      pictureUrl,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    };
    return userRef.set(updatedUserObject).then(() => updatedUserObject);
  }
}
```

[image: There error I'm getting]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue on my side, all is working as expected with your code, check the version of the Firebase/firestore scripts and try update these if there are not the latest.

This is my sample file that it is working also I added a promise to validate if the doc is present on the database, both methods are working on my side.

```html
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "m",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: ""
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        var firestore = firebase.firestore();

        async function saveUserInFirestore(userData) {
            const userRef = await firestore.collection('users').doc(userData.uid);
            const userDoc = await userRef.get();
            
            console.log(userDoc) //not undefined
            
            if(userDoc.exists){
                
                console.log("found1")
            }else{
                console.log("not exists1")
            }

            // testing on a promise
            userRef.get()
                .then((docSnapshot) => {
                    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
                        console.log("found")
                        userRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
                            // do stuff with the data
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("not exists")
                         //userRef.set({}) define the object if this is not in the database
                    }
                });
        }
```